# C Circular Doubly Linked List with static head initialization of next/prev pointers to static head address

Tags: c, memory, linked-list, initialization

I want to initialize a Circular Doubly Linked List next/previous pointers to point at the address of a statically allocated element used as sentinel/first element. In this way, I can simplify the list operations. I tried the following code:

```
struct ErrorDataElement {
    struct ErrorDataElement *next;
    struct ErrorDataElement *prev;
    
    enum ErrorType type;
    int code;
    char **messages;
    char *file;
    char *function;
    int line;
} _errorList = { &_errorList, &_errorList, 0, -1, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0 };
```

When I print `&_errorList` memory address (in a sub-function called from main() function) I get a different address from `_errorList.next` and `_errorList.prev`.

`_errorList.next` and `_errorList.prev` have coherently the same value.

If I inspect using the following code:

```
printf("%d %d", _errorList.code, _errorList.next->code);
```

I see that `_errorList.code = -1` as expected, while `_errorList.next->code = 1001`, indicating to me that the value of `_errorList.next` has been initialized to some incorrect memory address.
I suspect this is due to relative/absolute memory addressing during function initialization, but I can't figure out exactly and how to correctly initialize the static element, or whether or not is even possible such initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue. When I execute this, it prints the expected result :

```
void afunc(struct ErrorDataElement *elem) {
    printf("%p %p %p\n", elem, elem->next, elem->prev); 
    printf("%d %d %d\n", elem->code, elem->next->code, elem->prev->code); 
}

int main() {
    afunc(&_errorList); // prints ==> 0x601030 0x601030 0x601030
                        //            -1 -1 -1
    return 0;
}
```

The same is true if I print directly from main and I cannot find a case where what you explain happens. Cannot you show your exact codes ?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm trying to reproduce the bug in a small scale but I don't succeed. My setup is a project with 10k+ lines (so I can't post it here entirely) but the relevant part/setup is an error.c file which contains the code above, an error.h which wraps some functions with macros, and several other modules that include error.h and call the error management functions. I build all the object files separately and then I link them together.
If I setup a small scale error.c/error.h/main.c project, I build error.o/main.o and link them together, as you posted above, it works.

Comment: I don't know why, it started working suddenly without any apparent reason. Sorry to have wasted your time. Probably I should delete this question.

Comment: if I change the title, could this question be helpful for those who wonder how to initialize a circular doubly linked list?

Comment: I don't think you need to delete you question, I found it interesting because of the circularity and the way you declare and initialize the structure in one single form.